# com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties not found at compile

Tags: jax-ws, java

We used the class `JAXWSProperties` from the `com.sun.*` package in the code in order to set timeout properties like this:

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties;
...
Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
```

It compiles fine in the local Eclipse, but not on a continuous integration system (both using JDK 1.6). From researching this problem, I learned that the `com.sun.*` package should be avoided.

So my questions are:

- What causes the failed import at compile time?
- What should be used instead of `JAXWSProperties`?

Comment: Eclipse uses it's own compiler. Have you tried compiling the application on your local computer without using eclipse? Does that reproduce the problem on your CI server?

Comment: @flob Good point, thank you. You are right, it doesn't work either. So, can someone tell me, why the package is part of the rt.jar within the JDK, but is not found by the compiler?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've just had pretty much the same problem while converting one of our projects to run under Maven.

The solution I found, isn't really an ideal solution, in fact it's more of a "cludge" than a "fix," although it does run through the compiler OK. Like you I did a bit of research on this issue, and found a comment from Sun saying that these packages are hidden from the compiler, but are available to the JVM.

So, the solution I found was to simply find the string to which the constant was pointing, and use that locally.

In your case it would be:

```
final static String CONNECT_TIMEOUT = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout";
....
Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
ctxt.put(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
```

As I mentioned, this isn't ideal, and can not be guaranteed to work in future compiler releases, so use with care.

Comment: Thanks for the info, even though as you say this is more a cludge, it nevertheless helps solving the problem.