# Getting ClassNotFoundException: StreamingDataHandler

Tags: eclipse, jax-ws, jboss7.x, mtom

I'm developing a MTOM streaming web-service and have run into the following problem.
I have the following code in my webservice implementing class:

```
@Override
public void fileUpload(String name, DataHandler data) 
{
    System.out.println("INVOKING FILE UPLOAD!");

    try
    {
           StreamingDataHandler dh = (StreamingDataHandler) data;
           File file = File.createTempFile("result.txt", "");
           dh.moveTo(file);
           dh.close();
           System.out.println("TEMP FILE WITH DATA: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
           throw new WebServiceException(e);
    }
```

}

The problem is that Eclipse prompts me to import the StreamingDataHandler in the following way (compiles and deploys - ok):

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.StreamingDataHandler;
```

However, I get a ClassNotFoundException at runtime. Could you tell me what should be exported so that it simply works? I tried to include jaxws-ri.jar and stax-ex.jar (v 2.2.7) into my module but without any luck (get other errors). Also the StreamingDataHandler class is under a different package in them (same as prompted by Eclipse but without "internal"). My Project Facets are: Dynamic Web-Module 3.0, Java 1.7, Javascript 1.0, JBoss Web Services Core, server runtime is JBoss 7.1.1. How could I resolve the confusion? Thx.

**UPDATE: (solution)**

Use this code to write the data:

```
InputStream is = data.getInputStream(); // DataHandler
File file = File.createTempFile("result.txt", "");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Just sent 5.9Gb data between two hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.StreamingDataHandler` is in `rt.jar`.

Anyway you shouldn't use `sun` or `com.sun` packages in your application.

This Oracle article states why : [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html).

Those packages are not part of the official and supported Java specification. Using them might lead to incompatibilities between different versions of Java or different implementation (proprietary implementation like IBM and HP). Indeed you are not sure  that a sun class you got in one implementation will be part of an other one.

Comment: Thx. I found that the same class is also located in the org.jvnet.staxex ("org" is portable). However, now I get the "javax.activation.DataHandler cannot be cast to org.jvnet.staxex.StreamingDataHandler" exception. Do you know what the reason might be?

Comment: I guess the class in `org.jvnet.staxex` is something totally different. Hence your `data` field which is really an instance of a class from a `sun` package can't be convert in the `StreamingDataHandler` from the other package.

Comment: Hmm. According to this: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/1.2/stax-ex-1.2-javadoc.jar!/org/jvnet/staxex/StreamingDataHandler.html the StreamingDataHandler is a child of DataHandler. Then its clear why casting won't work (parent -> child). However, all the examples on MTOM that I see in the Internet have this sample code where such casting is done. :-/

Comment: No you're wrong. The parameter is DataHandler, hence you can pass as parameter any subtype of DataHandler, StreamingDataHandler is a child so it's allowed. But if you do so you have to be sure that the DataHandler object is actually an instance of `StreamingDataHandler` because you cast it in the first line. Now your problem is the object passed in the parameter is an instance from `sun` but in your code `dh` is supposed to be an instance of `StreamingDataHandler ` from `org.jvnet`.

Comment: If you want to make it work you must use the class from `rt.jar` but again it's not recommended to use `sun` classes (mainly for portability purpose)

Comment: Found the solution. It seems that simply reading from the DataHandler and writing to some outputstream works fine. Use the code marked as UPDATE above.

Comment: Yes actually that's the common algo I used to send data too :). This one is better because it doesn't use any `sun` package. I didn't realize you just wanted to send/receive data, if I did I'd give you that code!

Comment: The "JAXWSProperties" which is required to enable chunking is located in a "com" package. How do you overcome that? I.e. Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext();
ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.HTTP_CLIENT_STREAMING_CHUNK_SIZE, 8192 * 10);

Comment: This string definition is : `public static final String HTTP_CLIENT_STREAMING_CHUNK_SIZE = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.streaming.chunk.size";` You can just copy that in your code. I think it's the only trick, in this similar post : http://stackoverflow.com/q/7358724/1140748, the answer suggest the same solution.